# How to instantiate an interface, with a generic parameter

Tags: c#, interface

I have some classes that implement the interface below:

```
ISearchBase<T>
```

But I don't know which class will be instantiated, so I let "the user decide", like the example below:

```
var objectResponse = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(ResponseNamespace));
```

The problem is:
Each those classes has a return and I'm trying to use like this:

```
var object = (ISearchBase<objectResponse >)
          Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Namespace));
```

But the compiler won't let me do this... What can I do?

The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'objectResponse' could not be found.

Comment: What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: Has a return?? What error are you getting? You can't instantiate interfaces, so could you be a bit clearer about where you are running into trouble?

Comment: You can't instantiate interface. You definitely need to add some clarity to your post.

Comment: Also add some approximate code you hoping to achieve of using result of the operation (assuming it succeed).

Comment: You can't do `var object = (ISearchBase<X>)...` unless you know `X` at compile time.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is a final answer?

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte since is is not clear what you actually want to achieve then Enigmativity's answer is indeed the only answer possible.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte - Yes, it can't be done. There may be ways around it if we knew what you were going to do with `object` next though.

Comment: @Enigmativity, please, give your comment as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var object = (ISearchBase<X>)...` you **must** know the type `X` at compile time. The `var` keyword is just short-hand for the compiler to infer the type. So, you cannot use a run-time type to resolve for `X`.

You haven't shown what you what to do with the `object` after you've created it. It is certainly possible to call a generic method using reflection to allow you to type-safe code, but I can't tell if that will be useful to you or not without seeing more code.